# mySQL Query get record that dont match

Tags: mysql

I have an sql query that I wish to add another condition to but I cant seem to get it work. The query is simple enough:

```
SELECT DISTINCT monthly_returns.company_id
       FROM monthly_returns, paidreturns
       WHERE monthly_returns.company_id = paidreturns.company_id
       AND paidreturns.month =  '$cdate'
       AND paidreturns.paid =0
```

However I wish to get the records also from the monthly_returns that have not record at all in paidreturns for the give date. I know it would be something like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    monthly_returns
WHERE   monthly_returns NOT IN (SELECT * FROM paidreturns WHERE paidreturns.month =  '$cdate')
```

paidreturns.paid =0 is where the bill has not been paid, but equally if there is no record for that date in paidreturns then the bill is also not paid.

The schema

**paidreturns table**

-id

-company_id

-paid

-month

-total

**monthly_returns table**

-id

-company_id

-wage_totals

-month

Comment: You might consider using `LEFT JOIN` to join `paidreturns` to `monthly_returns`. That will return all `monthly_returns` regardless of whether there is a matching row in `paidreturns`. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT monthly_returns.company_id
FROM
    monthly_returns
LEFT JOIN
    paidreturns
    ON monthly_returns.company_id = paidreturns.company_id
       AND monthly_returns.month = paidreturns.month
WHERE 
    monthly_returns.month = '$cdate'
    AND
        (
        paidreturns.paid = 0
        OR
        paidreturns.company_id IS NULL
        );
```

Using a `LEFT JOIN`, you can find all records from `monthly_returns`, regardless of whether they matched an entry from `paidreturns`.

Then, by adding `paidreturns.company_id IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause, you include those unmatched entries in your query.

Comment: I am getting Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'paidreturns' in 'where clause'

Comment: I just updated it, but still a little fuzzy on your schema. Can you post your output from `DESC paidreturns;` and a `DESC monthly_returns;`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, the sql now runs but always gives back zero records I will post the scheme

Comment: I have checked few dates now it will give the usual results if there is records in paidreturns with paid=0 but still nothing for those that have a monthly_return record but nothing in the paid returns

Comment: It looks like you might need to `LEFT JOIN` on the `month` as well as the `company_id`. I've updated my answer. Does that work?

Comment: perfect, thanks for the help. I was on the wrong track with that one

Answer (score 0):

```
select company_id
from
(
(

SELECT DISTINCT monthly_returns.company_id
   FROM monthly_returns, paidreturns
   WHERE monthly_returns.company_id = paidreturns.company_id
   AND paidreturns.month =  '$cdate'
   AND paidreturns.paid =0
)
union
(


SELECT  company_id
FROM    monthly_returns
WHERE   monthly_returns NOT IN (SELECT * FROM paidreturns WHERE paidreturns.month = '$cdate'
)
) as x
```

Comment: you may want to change the second part of the union to make an inner join to paidreturns with paidvalue = 0

Comment: thanks for the replay, I get You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as x' at line 20